# Find class anywhere in div's descendants

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap accordion/well with form elements in each accordion section. As a user navigates through the different fields and accordion sections, I would like a span to appear based on whether or not they filled out all the required data. All the input fields sit within `.section`. If a user doesn't fill out a required field, the `.form-group` around the input and label gets the class `.has-error`. When they fix the issue, `.has-error` is replaced with `.no-error`.

So if the `.has-error` class appears anywhere in `.section` (all descendants including grandchildren), the span `.field-error` should appear in `.lbl.lblBig`, which is the sibling immediately before `.section` and contains the title for that accordion's section. If `.has-error` isn't anywhere in sight, then I want the span `.field-ok` to show inside `.lbl.lblBig`.

Here's rudimentary layout:

```
 <div class="lbl lblBig">
      Section 1
      <span class="field-error" style="display:none"></span>
      <span class="field-ok" style="display:none"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="section"> <!--input fields for section 1-->
      <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">First</label>
           <input class="required form-control" placeholder="First">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Last</label>
           <input class="required form-control" placeholder="Last">
      </div>
 </div>
 <div class="lbl lblBig">
      Section 2
      <span class="field-error" style="display:none"></span>
      <span class="field-ok" style="display:none"></span>
 </div>
 <div class="section"> <!--input fields for section 2-->
      <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">Street</label>
           <input class="required form-control" placeholder="Street">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
           <label class="control-label">City</label>
           <input class="required form-control" placeholder="City">
      </div>
 </div>
```

I've put together this script, but it doesn't work. I don't need the `.no-error` class, but I created it in an attempt to get something working. I'm having trouble searching through `.section`'s decedents and using that info to change `.lbl.lblBig`.

```
$(".section").each(function(){
    if ($(this).find(".has-error").length) {
        $(this).prev(".lbl.lblBig").find(".field-error").show();
        $(this).prev(".lbl.lblBig").find(".field-ok").hide();
    }
    else if ($(this).find(".no-error").//do opposite of length? ) {
        $(this).prev(".lbl.lblBig").find(".field-error").hide();
        $(this).prev(".lbl.lblBig").find(".field-ok").show();
    }
});
```

I can't change any of the page's and form's HTML, so I'm limited in that regard. Any help would be greatly appreciated. If I could, I would bake you a cookie, but this is the internet, and there is no 3D print-baking technology. Thank you.

Comment: You really can't change anything in the html you provide ? If you added the attribute `required` in each `<input>` it would do all the job for you when the submit button is clicked.

Comment: I wish I could, but no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your condition expression should be `if (length > 0)`.

```
$(".section").each(function(){
    if ($(this).find(".has-error").length > 0) {
        $(this).prev(".lbl.lblBig").find(".field-error").show();
        $(this).prev(".lbl.lblBig").find(".field-ok").hide();
    }
    else {
        $(this).prev(".lbl.lblBig").find(".field-error").hide();
        $(this).prev(".lbl.lblBig").find(".field-ok").show();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9dbyq2v3/